# How to add all the possible combinations of two lists without using two nested loops?

Tags: python-3.x

lis1=[3,4,5]
lis2=[1,2,3,4]

How to produce this below res_ list from lis1 and lis2 without using two nested for loops?
res_=[4,5,6,7,5,6,7,8,6,7,8,9]   #sum of all combinations.

How to produce that result without using tow nested loops?

Comment: There is no way to do this without two nested loops. All you can do is *not explicitly write* the loops, but they will be executed by some helper function either way. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools for that:

```
import itertools
lis1=[3,4,5]
lis2=[1,2,3,4]

[sum(x) for x in itertools.product(lis1,lis2)]
#Out[24]: [4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```